# How to redirect to external website on 404 Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat7

I am using spring 3 + Tomcat 7

In `web.xml` I have defined

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/filenotfound</location>
</error-page>
```

But i want to redirect to external url say `www.google.com` instead of `/filenotfound` . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure whether giving the direct url in location will work. But you can put a jsp there and redirect to the url from the jsp.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/filenotfound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

filenotfound.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<c:redirect url="http://hotmail.com" />
```

Comment: You aren't going to get a cleaner solution than this. To quote the Servlet spec "The sub-element location element contains the location of the resource in the web application relative to the root of the web application. The value of the location must have a leading ‘/’." There is no way to do what you want to do directly in an <error-page> element.