# A general tomcat (v7) 404 redirect to external url

Tags: jsp, tomcat, redirect, tomcat7

After testing several suggestions (like [Redirect to external website on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548217/how-to-redirect-to-external-website-on-404-tomcat)), I am still not able to have a redirect to an external url for non existing webapps in tomcat.

My situation is the following:

- tomcat runs on the url localhost
- a lot of webapps running in the directory webapps/app1, webapps/app2, ...
- a url call on localhost/app1 will open the app app1
- a url call on localhost/app2 will open the app app2
- a url call on localhost will open app1 (automatic redirect configured in tomcat)

My goal is to achieve a **redirect to an external website** like http://www.test.com/404.html when someone enters a url like *localhost/asdf*. Is there a way I can achieve this globally in tomcat like adding the errorpage property in /conf/web.xml?

**Answered here:**
[How to handle not available Tomcat 7 webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101895/how-to-handle-not-available-tomcat-7-webapps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle not available Tomcat 7 webapps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101895/how-to-handle-not-available-tomcat-7-webapps)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat version = ?

What exactly do you want?

A. If you want to redirect non-existent web applications elsewhere, then configure the `error-page` in the ROOT web application (aka the default web application).

The ROOT web application handles all requests that have not been handled by other web applications.

B. If you want to configure a default setting for "error 404" handling across all web applications:

It would be rather hard to share a JSP page between web applications (YMMV), but it is very easy to share a servlet.

- Prepare a servlet that performs the redirection.

  E.g. extend `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` and override its "service" method. Something like this:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // TODO: check that request.getMethod() is one of "GET", "HEAD", "POST"?

      response.sendRedirect("http://www.test.com/404.html");

      //// Or if you want better control over HTTP status code (302/307/...):
      // response.reset();
      // response.setStatus(302);
      // response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.test.com/404.html");
   }
  ```
- Put your code into `lib` directory of Tomcat — as a jar or as a package/class files tree.
- Configure your servlet in `conf/web.xml` and map it onto some URL there, e.g. `/WEB-INF/404`

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>bar</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>foo.Bar</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>bar</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/404</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- Configure `error-page` in `conf/web.xml` with location served by that servlet.

  ```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/404</location>
  </error-page>
  ```

If this does not help, one can also extend the `ErrorReportValve` class.