# How to change the liferay/tomcat "The requested resource () is not available." page

Tags: tomcat, liferay, http-status-code-404, liferay-6

How to create a custom page for 404 in tomcat/liferay:

[image: How to create a custom 404 tomcat/liferay page]

I tried to change the Liferay 404 page which can be done through the `portal-ext.properties` file but that only affects the first level of URL ex. `localhost/notfoundpage`

But for the layouts under `localhost/web/notfoundpage` the resource not found page is being served instead of the configured 404 page.

Comment: I think this is not related to Liferay, this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548217/how-to-redirect-to-external-website-on-404-tomcat) can help you